# How can I get Time.time as a fixed integer after an event happens in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to display on the screen that the player has achieved their goals in this much time after playing the game. But when I display Time.time it keeps changing. I want to record the time elapsed when the event happens and display it as a fixed number string.

Answer (score 0):

When the player achieves the goal, store Time.time in a class variable (i.e. declared inside the class but outside of any function). Then display that variable rather than Time.time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to record the result of the game? If so, you can try to create a new canvas in the scene, and create a new image in the canvas as the background image. You can set the relevant properties of the image through the Inspector interface.

[image]

After setting the background, add a Button to the scene, and set the different states of the Button when it is pressed, lifted, and disabled according to personal needs. And add a C# script file under canvas - StartMenuController

[image]

The start interface code is:

```
   public void OnStartGameButtonClick()
     {
     //When the button is pressed, jump to the game interface
     SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
     //The parameter in the LoadScene() function can be the number of interfaces in builtsettings or the scene name
      }
```

The end interface code is:

```
    public void OnExitButtonClick()
    {
       Application.Quit();
    }
```

Point each function in the canvas to the onClick of the respective button.Hope it helps you thank you

Answer (score 0):

Access the data generated by the player, and then read it out. Does this idea help you?
Create a new C# code in Unity, copy the following code into it and mount it on an empty object. The following code is divided into two methods: SaveGame (save data) and LodeGame (read data). You can create two Buttons in the game and create click events respectively.

```
public Inventory myInventory;//Data to be saved
public Item HpMedicine;//Data to be saved

public void SaveGame() //Save game method
{
    Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath);
    if (!Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_SaveGame"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_SaveGame");
    }

    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();//Binary conversion

    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_SaveGame/Inventory.txt");

    var json0 = JsonUtility.ToJson(myInventory);//Data Json conversion to be saved
    var json1 = JsonUtility.ToJson(HpMedicine);//Data Json conversion to be saved
    var json2 = JsonUtility.ToJson(MpMedicine);//Data Json conversion to be saved

    formatter.Serialize(file, json0);//Saved data
    formatter.Serialize(file, json1);//Saved data
    formatter.Serialize(file, json2);//Saved data

    file.Close();
}

public void LoadGame()//Read the game method
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_SaveGame/Inventory.txt"))
    {
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_SaveGame/Inventory.txt", FileMode.Open);

        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite((string)bf.Deserialize(file), myInventory);//Saved data
        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite((string)bf.Deserialize(file), HpMedicine);//Saved data
        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite((string)bf.Deserialize(file), MpMedicine);//Saved data

        file.Close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I misunderstood your question because as I understand it, this is the answer.

just save Time.time into some varaible on event.

```
// for example..
public float attackTime;

public void OnAttack() => attackTime = Time.time; // now use attackTime...
```